# Configure Wireguard to block all non-ssh traffic

Tags: iptables, wireguard

I am trying to restrict my Wireguard VPN to only allow SSH connections between the clients and I am struggling to setup proper iptables `PostUp` rules for the wireguard server.

My Interface has the following `PostUp` rules:

```
PostUp   = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This for some reason allows access to all ports.

I have also tried to use `iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp ! -dport 22 -j DROP` as an additional very first rule. But for some reason I only managed to configure to block all traffic (including ssh).

Is there any way to allow the clients to only have access to port 22?

Comment: Is SSH really only between clients?  I am confused about what you are trying to do with the `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` rule

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried to condense my setup, but maybe that was a mistake. In truth wireguard is running on a cloud machine that acts as a (NAT) router that allows the wireguard clients to access an internal network. That is what the masquerade is doing. I am not sure if that changes anything with the filters.

Comment: One more thing, in case it helps. The machine has only one physical interface: `eth0` and the wireguard (virtual) interface is `wg0server`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be tempted to add a chain called perhaps called wireguard or something else with rules like these.  These would be get added by something outside wireguard.

```
# create wireguard chain
iptables -t filter -N wireguard
# permit anything coming from or going to port 22
iptables -t filter -A wireguard -p tcp --dport 1024:65535 --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A wireguard -p tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# drop everything else
iptables -t filter -A wireguard -j DROP
```

Then in your wireguard PostUp, just add rules like this.

```
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -i %i -j wireguard
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -o %i -j wireguard
```

Comment: This seems to work. It just took me some time as I think I had some rules left over in my iptables. This help clear them: https://serverfault.com/a/200658/457440 . After your suggestions worked really well. Using a separate chain also helped debugging a lot.